# Error while setting up azure iot on raspberry Pi

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli

I am trying to connect Raspberry Pi 3 via Azure IoT and I am following this [guide](https://indeema.com/blog/connecting-raspberry-pi-via-azure-iot--step-by-step-tutorial). In Step 5 of setting up the Azure CLI, I have encountered this error:

> Unable to load extension 'azure-cli-iot-ext: unrecognized kwargs: ['min_profile']'. Use --debug for more information.

> Unable to load extension 'azure-iot: unrecognized kwargs: ['min_profile']'. Use --debug for more information.

Does anyone know what is the resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely caused due to the older version of the Azure CLI.

You could quickly check the Azure CLI Version using `az --version`

You must have at least base version of **v2.3.1** for installing the Azure IOT extensions.

Comment: I tried to do Az upgrade but  have already the latest version